# JWT and server side token storage

Tags: token, jwt

Every article I've read vouching for the advantages of JWT state that one of these advantages is its ability for an auth system to be distributed across multiple servers. i.e . You aren't relying on a central repository of user auth details to do a lookup on every request.

However when it comes to implementation, I've read in many places that for added security you shouldn't just rely on the JWT signature verification itself, and that you should maintain a list of black or white list tokens generated by the server.

Doesn't this defeat the advantage I've listed above, as this list of tokens would need to be stored centrally where all servers can access it and it would require a lookup on each request?

How have people implemented this on their end?

Answer (score 2):

You are making very good points in your question. Actually it would make sense to store an OAuth token at a central location in order to make it easier to implement signout/revoke functionality. If you just relied on the token signature you couldn't have possibly implemented such feature. Suppose that a user wanted to revoke an access token. In this case if you didn't have a central location/datastore for those tokens where you would have invalidated it and only relied on token signature, then the token would still have been valid.

So indeed, when you want to build more advanced systems that are dependent on OAuth tokens, a central store for those tokens is more than a must.